# extract xlsx files from a calendar for creating a dataframe of all the data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tying to download the *.xlsx file for each day from this [dailycoal_link](https://npp.gov.in/dailyCoalReports). Everyday the file is updated at the end of the day but before capturing the files for the future dates, I thought I could bulk download for the earlier dates until today.This is the code I wrote.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = 'https://npp.gov.in/public-reports/cea/daily/'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('a')
filelink = []
for link in tags:
    if ('dailyCoal1-' in link.get('href','')):
    Print(link.get('href'))
    filelink.append(link.get('href'))

for links in filelink:
    wget.download(links)
```

For a sample, if you click on earlier date, any date and then right click the xlsx file to extract the url, you will get this link

https://npp.gov.in/public-reports/cea/daily/fuel/11-02-2021/dailyCoal1-2021-02-11.xlsx

I want to understand how to get these files from this process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you generate the urls yourself and then just download the files?

Here's how:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

import requests


def date_range(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)


base_url = "https://npp.gov.in/public-reports/cea/daily/fuel/"

for single_date in date_range(date(2021, 2, 1), date(2021, 2, 11)):
    date_one = single_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    date_two = single_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    file_url = f"{base_url}{date_one}/dailyCoal1-{date_two}.xlsx"
    print(f"Fetching: {file_url}")
    with open(file_url.rsplit("/")[-1], "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(file_url, verify=False).content)
```

> **NOTE!** `verify=False` *disables certificate verification and without this there is no [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack protection*.

Output is a bunch of `.xlsx` files in your script's directory:

```
dailyCoal1-2021-02-01.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-02.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-03.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-04.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-05.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-06.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-07.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-08.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-09.xlsx
dailyCoal1-2021-02-10.xlsx
```

Comment: oh I didn't know I could change URL !! this is amazing... Thanks a lot ! But why does it give this error when I do verify = True ---- SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='npp.gov.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /public-reports/cea/daily/fuel/01-02-2021/dailyCoal1-2021-02-01.xlsx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))